# How to change command text of SqlCommandBuilder.InsertCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I want to modify `SqlCommandBuilder` to retrieve `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value after an insert, without creating a stored procedure for each of 2000+ tables.

I'm trying this code:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.Categories", connection);                          

DataTable categories = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(categories);
...

SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText+
            +"; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS SCOPEIDENTITY";
            ...
adapter.Update(categories);
```

But no matter what I type, the `DataAdapter` executes the SQL statement that existed in the beginning - not my changes.

Even this text does not produce a SQL error:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "Hello world";
adapter.Update(categories);
```

SQL Server profiler shows this SQL statement instead of error.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryName]) VALUES (@p1)',N'@p1 nvarchar(12)',@p1=N'New Category'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SqlCommand manual page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) says the following:

> You can reset the CommandText property and reuse the SqlCommand object.
>   However, you must close the SqlDataReader before you can execute a new or
>   previous command.

It doesn't look like you are using a SqlDataReader, but this might apply to the SqlDataAdapter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.GetInsertCommand().Clone();
```

Comment: Please add some details and add your line as a code.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.Categories", connection);                          

DataTable categories = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(categories);

SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand().Clone();
adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID";
adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
adapter.Update(categories);